# Get value from XML file by its name using PHP

Tags: php, xml

How I can get a name and value stored in `<set name = "height">` tag using the name of value I mean `"height"` in this case? Its ofcourse XML file and I'm using PHP.

```
<list>
<npc id="25001" name="Greyclaw Kutus" title="Raid Boss">
<set name="level" val="23"/>
<set name="radius" val="21"/>
<set name="height" val="43.5"/>
<set name="rHand" val="67"/>
<set name="lHand" val="633"/>
<set name="sp" val="67170"/>
<set name="hp" val="40330.25972324"/>
<set name="mp" val="231.96"/>
<set name="hpRegen" val="17.5347470979605"/>
</npc>
</list>
```

I've made something like this I have no idea how to itarete whole file by this:

```
<?php
$list = simplexml_load_file('25000-25999.xml');

if($list === false){
echo "File open error";
}
else {

foreach($list ->npc as $npc) {
 $att = "height";

 $val = $list->npc->xpath('set[@name="' . $att . '"]');

 foreach ($val as $value) {
     echo $value['val'];
 }
 }
```

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: You provide us with a wrong xml + you have not tried anything by yourself. SO community is not here to do the work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are accessing the 'height' element, you are accessing using `$list->npc` as the basis of your XPath expression.  This will give you the first element each time ( and always echo 43.5).  You need to change this to use `$npc`, so that each time the XPath is relative to the current element of npc...

```
   $val = $npc->xpath('set[@name="' . $att . '"]');
```